# Need some major batch-fu

Tags: batch-file, copy, dos

I have this massive folder structure with thousands of folders and subfolders.  I need to copy  all the DLLs from this structure into a single folder.

I've tried the

```
xcopy *.dll c:\output /S /E
```

but that copies the DLLs with the structure.

Is there a way to do what I want in a batch file using DOS commands only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at a duplicate of this at

[superuser: xcopy files into single directory](https://superuser.com/questions/20038/xcopy-files-into-single-directory)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming no spaces in folder/file names:

```
for /r %f in (*.dll) do copy %f %~nf.dll
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  Say I want to copy DLLs from c:\largeStructure to c:\onlyDLLs.  What would the line be?

Comment: it would be for /r c:\largeStructure %f in (*.dll) do @copy "%f" c:\onlyDLLs